# How to implement SwipeView?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to swipe each image to switch to another image like gallery app. I am now using this https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView, but I don't know how to implement it. Should I drag a collection view inside my PhotoDetailViewController, or I only use it in coding. May anyone help me with this.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AAShareBubbles
import SwipeView

class PhotoDetailViewController: UIViewController, AAShareBubblesDelegate, SwipeViewDataSource, SwipeViewDelegate {


  @IBOutlet var topView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet var bottomView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet var photoImageView: UIImageView!
  var photoImage = UIImage()
  var checkTapGestureRecognize = true
  var swipeView: SwipeView = SwipeView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    title = "Photo Detail"
    super.viewDidLoad()
    photoImageView.image = photoImage
    swipeView.dataSource = self
    swipeView.delegate = self
    let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeMethod")
    swipeView.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
    swipeView.addSubview(photoImageView)
    swipeView.pagingEnabled = false
    swipeView.wrapEnabled = true

  }

  func swipeView(swipeView: SwipeView!, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView! {
    return photoImageView
  }

  func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("SwipeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwipeViewPhotoCell
    return cell
  }

  @IBAction func onBackClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
  }


  @IBAction func onTabGestureRecognize(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("on tap")
    if checkTapGestureRecognize == true {
      bottomView.hidden = true
      topView.hidden = true
      self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
      let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
      let screenWidth = screenSize.width
      let screenHeight = screenSize.height
      photoImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
      checkTapGestureRecognize = false
      showAminationOnAdvert()
    }
    else if checkTapGestureRecognize == false {
      bottomView.hidden = false
      topView.hidden = false
      self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
      checkTapGestureRecognize = true
    }
  }

  func showAminationOnAdvert() {
    let transitionAnimation = CATransition();
    transitionAnimation.type = kCAEmitterBehaviorValueOverLife
    transitionAnimation.subtype = kCAEmitterBehaviorValueOverLife
    transitionAnimation.duration = 2.5
    transitionAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transitionAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
    photoImageView.layer.addAnimation(transitionAnimation, forKey: "fadeAnimation")

  }


  @IBAction func onShareTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("share")

    let myShare = "I am feeling *** today"

    let shareVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //    print("share bubles")
    //    let shareBubles: AAShareBubbles = AAShareBubbles.init(centeredInWindowWithRadius: 100)
    //    shareBubles.delegate = self
    //    shareBubles.bubbleRadius = 40
    //    shareBubles.sizeToFit()
    //    //shareBubles.showFacebookBubble = true
    //    shareBubles.showTwitterBubble = true
    //    shareBubles.addCustomButtonWithIcon(UIImage(named: "twitter"), backgroundColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), andButtonId: 100)
    //    shareBubles.show()

  }

  @IBAction func playAutomaticPhotoImages(sender: AnyObject) {
    animateImages(0)
  }

  func animateImages(no: Int) {
    var number: Int = no
    if number == images.count - 1 {
      number = 0
    }
    let name: String = images[number]
    self.photoImageView!.alpha = 0.5
    self.photoImageView!.image = UIImage(named: name)

    //code to animate bg with delay 2 and after completion it recursively calling animateImage method
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.8, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {() in
      self.photoImageView!.alpha = 1.0;
      },
      completion: {(Bool) in
        number++;
        self.animateImages(number);
        print(String(images[number]))
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag and drop a UIView to your storyboard/XIB, and set its customclass to SwipeView.

Also set the delegate and datasource to the view controller which includes the UIView you just dragged.

Then in the viewcontroller, implement the required delegate methods similar to how you'd implement the methods for a tableview.

Comment: I have an image in my viewcontroller, and some label, button on the top, bot  of this image, I have an array string of image. So I don't have to drag and drop a UIView because I have an imageview??

Comment: @khuong291you still have to drag and drop a UIView, set it's custom class to SwipeView, and then implement this method, - (UIView *)swipeView:(SwipeView *)swipeView viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view;

where in you provide another UIView or the UIImageView to be displayed.

Comment: @khuong291please accept my answer if you think it helped you.